# Creating count-down application for desktop background c#

Tags: c#

I would like to write a small application which will be a countdown application, it's basically should have no frame and no background - just a counts the time from now to a date set in app.config.

I know how to write the countdown itself. My problem is that I don't know which kind of application can have no form ?

How can I make something look like that? what type of application should I create?

thanks

Comment: does your application need to show digits? Or just background counter?

Comment: More or less any kind of application can be windowless. The most simply way to do this (if you do not need a service) is to create a Windows Application (with WinForms) and do not call Application.Run(). Keep the Program.Main() function and call all your stuff there then simply return when you finished.

Comment: Might check out Transparent windows in WPF http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2007/06/20/transparent-windows-in-wpf-2/

Comment: My application should show the digits, the background will be invisible, and so does the form.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions for you.

Solution 1 would be writing it as a Service

http://industriousone.com/blog/writing-windows-services-c

Solution 2 would use a WinForm, then set visible to false so it doesn't appear. It'll still work in the background.

Comment: He doesn't need to create a window and to make it invisible, it's enough...to do **not create** the window at all.

Comment: I was assuming he might want to use the Winforms timer? But yeah that'd work well enough.

Comment: If I set visible to false I won't see the countdown, I want to see the countdown, I just don't want it to be in a window...